# Smack facebook login not authorized

Tags: java, android, facebook, xmpp, smack

I am quite stuck on implementing facebook chat in my android application. I am using XMPP connection offered by aSmack library. Everything works fine, if i'm using PLAIN mechanism and my regular facebook username and password, like so

`SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
xmpp.login("my_username@mail.com", "my_password");`

But if i'm using X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM mechanism to login with my app id and access token, then i am getting always not authrized error.

This is my main login method:

```
public void testLogin(){
        SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com",5222);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);

        XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);

        try {
            //Async connecting to XMPPConnection
            new ConnectXMPP().execute(xmpp).get();

            Log.i("XMPPClient",
                    "Connected to " + xmpp.getHost());

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(1500);

            xmpp.login("145537185371985731", "145537185371985731|W3-5DTut4qFoNuBapOI-f5Bo_eQ", "Application");

            Log.i("10201970684380516", "Logged in to " + xmpp.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is my SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism class

```
public class SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism extends SASLMechanism {

    private static final String NAME = "X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM";

    private String apiKey = "";
    private String access_token = "";

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
        super(saslAuthentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authenticate() throws IOException, XMPPException {

        getSASLAuthentication().send(new AuthMechanism(NAME, ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String apiKey, String host, String acces_token)
            throws IOException, XMPPException {
        if (apiKey == null || acces_token == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid parameters");
        }

        this.access_token = acces_token;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.hostname = host;

        String[] mechanisms = { NAME };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props,
                this);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticate(String username, String host, CallbackHandler cbh)
            throws IOException, XMPPException {
        String[] mechanisms = { NAME };
        Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.sc = Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props,
                cbh);
        authenticate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void challengeReceived(String challenge) throws IOException {
        byte[] response = null;

        if (challenge != null) {
            String decodedChallenge = new String(Base64.decode(challenge));
            Map<String, String> parameters = getQueryMap(decodedChallenge);

            String version = "1.0";
            String nonce = parameters.get("nonce");
            String method = parameters.get("method");

            long callId = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();

            String composedResponse = "api_key="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8") + "&call_id=" + callId
                    + "&method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8")
                    + "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8")
                    + "&access_token="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(access_token, "utf-8") + "&v="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8");

            response = composedResponse.getBytes("utf-8");
        }

        String authenticationText = "";

        if (response != null) {
            authenticationText = Base64.encodeBytes(response,
                    Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES);
        }

        // Send the authentication to the server
        getSASLAuthentication().send(new Response(authenticationText));
    }

    private Map<String, String> getQueryMap(String query) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String[] params = query.split("\\&");

        for (String param : params) {
            String[] fields = param.split("=", 2);
            map.put(fields[0], (fields.length > 1 ? fields[1] : null));
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

And there's the exception i am getting always.

```
    D/SMACK﹕ 09:26:38 ɣetrɔ SENT (308528663): <auth mechanism="X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"></auth>
    02-26 21:26:38.871    3810-3837/com.example.transporter D/SMACK﹕ 09:26:38 ɣetrɔ RCV  (308528663): <challenge xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>dmVyc2lvbj0xJm1ldGhvZD1hdXRoLnhtcHBfbG9naW4mbm9uY2U9QzkyQjg1M0UwODFCQzNEQzI1NzRBQ0ZENUJDQUQyNTQ=</challenge>
    02-26 21:26:38.872    3810-3836/com.example.transporter D/SMACK﹕ 09:26:38 ɣetrɔ SENT (308528663): <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">YXBpX2tleT0xMDIwMTk3MDY4NDM4MDUxNiZjYWxsX2lkPTE0MjQ5Nzg3OTg4NzEmbWV0aG9kPWF1dGgueG1wcF9sb2dpbiZub25jZT1DOTJCODUzRTA4MUJDM0RDMjU3NEFDRkQ1QkNBRDI1NCZhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW49MTQ1MjYwMjYzODMwMTM1MCU3Q1czLTVEVHV0NHFGb051QmFwT0ktZjVCb19lUSZ2PTEuMA==</response>
    02-26 21:26:39.178    3810-3837/com.example.transporter D/SMACK﹕ 09:26:39 ɣetrɔ RCV  (308528663): <failure xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'><not-authorized/></failure></stream:stream>
    02-26 21:26:39.181    3810-3810/com.example.transporter W/System.err﹕ SASL authentication failed using mechanism X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM:
3810-3810/com.example.transporter W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:342)
02-26 21:26:39.184    3810-3810/com.example.transporter W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:230)
02-26 21:26:39.184    3810-3810/com.example.transporter W/System.err﹕ at com.example.transporter.activity.MainActivity.testLogin(MainActivity.java:188)
02-26 21:26:39.184    3810-3810/com.example.transporter W/System.err﹕ at com.example.transporter.activity.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:135)
```

Comment: Don't use it.Facebook xmpp chat will not be available after April 30th 2015. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog